# Graph "Vertex cover" brute algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

> Given an electrical network, which is a set of electric generators,
>   between which wires are stretched. A wire has current if at least one
>   generator is operating at one end of the wire. Find the set with
>   minimum count of generators that need to be turned on to provide
>   current to the entire network.

I found some extra information that can help. It is "Vertex cover problem".

Now we know that it hasn't special algorithm. Let's bruteforce?

Comment: This looks like a minimum vertex cover problem.

Comment: @jrook yes, it is! How can we solve it? For example, in `C++` language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you note in the question, this is an instance of the [vertex cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover). It is a classic NP-hard problem, meaning no known algorithm gives exact results while scaling efficiently to larger inputs. The associated decision problem, of testing whether a vertex cover with *k* or fewer vertices exists, is NP-complete.

So, if you need the true minimum number, then you are not going to be able to do much better than some kind of [backtracking search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking_search). If that's what you mean by "brute force" then unfortunately you're out of luck. Otherwise, if an approximation within a factor of 2 is good enough (i.e. a vertex cover with at most twice as many vertices as the true minimum), then one simple heuristic is to find a [maximal matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_matching) and then choose both vertices for each edge in the matching.