# Deterministic solutions to Minimal Vertex cover problems - NP complete is fine

Tags: algorithm, math, graph, graph-theory, np

A vertex cover problem is to find a set ψ for an undirected graph G = (V, E) for ψ ∈ V such that if {u, v} ∈ E then either u ∈ ψ or v ∈ ψ or both. This Problem is defined and proved to be NP complete.

Are there Deterministic Algorithms that can solve this problem? An exponential running time is acceptable but are there any better deterministic algorithms? [I found a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59201501/graph-vertex-cover-brute-algorithm) and only one approach [Using Binary search](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/finding-minimum-vertex-cover-graph-using-binary-search/). I am not looking for approximate solutions which can be run in lesser time - as I understand the one listed in Chapter 35 of Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest, and Stein (CLRS) text is an Approximation Algorithm.

Comment: Two notes: (1) You probably mean **Minimal** vertex cover (Otherwise,  ψ=V is a vertex cover as well). (2) What do you mean when you say "deterministic" in this context. There is [2-approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover#Approximate_evaluation) to this problem, meaning if minimal VC is of size `k`, then the algorithm will yield  ψ such that  |ψ|<=2k.

Comment: Deterministic solution converges every time and gives the accurate solution as compared to it NP-complete competitor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a search-tree for this problem. For every edge {v, w}, there are 3 options.

1. v is included
2. w is included
3. both are included.

You can also apply some pruning rules, like the following:

1. If a vertex v has degree 1, include the neighbour of v in the VC.
2. If for two neighbours v and w the neighbour-set of v is a subset of the neighbours of w, include w in the VC.

Both of these rules can be proven in the sense that the choice you make by these rules are at least as good as any other choice you could make for the considered edge.

Comment: If you want, I can expand a bit on how to write a search-tree algorithm